# Is there any theory for the following series expansion method of solving PDEs?

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a nonlinear PDE defined over the intervals $0 \leq t \leq 1$ and $0 
\leq x \leq x_{max}$, which has the following form:

$4t(1-t)U_t(x,t)=U_{xx}(x,t)+2xU_x(x,t)-4t[U(x,t)^2-U(x,t)]$.

I am looking for the solution in the form:

$U(x,t)=u_0(x) + u_1(x)t + u_2(x)t^2 + ...$

The PDE is accompanied by simple two-point Dirichlet boundary conditions:

$U(0,t)=0,  U(x_{max},t)=1$.

and a known initial condition. I get a system of two-point BVPs for the functions $u_i(x)$. I solve these BVPs numerically and the results appear reasonable, but the series is very slowly convergent when $t$ approaches 1.

Is there any theory telling when such a solution exists and what might be alternative expansions if the above one is not suitable? I would appreciate any pointers to the relevant literature.
I especially need some information concerning how to obtain an accurate and quickly convergent expansion valid in the limit of $t$ approaching 1, if the (above) expansion around $t=0$ is not convergent or very slowly convergent in this limit. I tried an expansion around $t=1$:

$U(x,t)=v_0(x) + v_1(x)(1-t) + v_2(x)(1-t)^2 + ...$

but I find that only the first two terms of this expansion agree with the solution, I don't understand why.

Leszek

Answer (score 1):

A bit strange, but

```
du/ds == t (1 - t) du/dt /. 
  {t -> E^s/(1 + E^s), dt -> D[E^s/(1 + E^s), s] ds} //  FullSimplify

 True
```

So its the standard diffusion operator $$\partial_s u - \partial_{x,x} u+\dots =0$$ with a drift term and a nonlinear production term.

Comment: Just for clarification, please: what software?

Comment: Yes, this PDE results from a certain reaction-diffusion problem, but the advantage of the present formulation is that an infinite (true)  time interval is reduced to the [0, 1] interval of t. Also, a growing-in-time spatial interval affected by diffusional changes is reduced to a fixed interval of x. Hence, by considering the present formulation one can consider a complete solution within a bounded t-x domain.

Comment: @paulgarrett The expression (minus the True) evaluates to True in Mathematica.